Fiddler Classic ни одним известным способом так и не ловит трафик из Firefox
Перепробовала много способов запустить перехват трафика с Firefox на Fiddler Classic. Ни одним не получилось:

прокси с портом меняла (127.0.0.1 , 8888/8866)
и Использовать системные настройки прокси - не мой вариант
FiddlerRoot выгружала, загружала, удаляла и по кругу
chartgpt спрашивала, делала его рекомендации - нет, не вышло
галочки, чекбоксы проверяла
в принципе перезагружала систему :)
плагин Fiddler поставила - не помог

Помогите, пожалуйста, наладить перехват.
